# How to reupload after fail using dropzone?

Tags: node.js, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to upload file, and I found a issue.

So I selected one image trought dropzone and click to upload(I'm using `autoProcessQueue:false`)

And assume the upload failed. there's will be a error-mark in above of the image.

Then I click upload again. by watching the developer tool bar I see that formdata.files is empty. no files are uploading to server.

Is it a bug? How can I reupload the images after fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code Taken from https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/617. The problem is on error, file.status is not updated to Dropzone.QUEUED.

```
view.dropzone = new Dropzone(form[0], {
    ...
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 1,
    thumbnailWidth: 300,
    thumbnailHeight: null,
    previewsContainer: inputPreview[0],
    clickable: inputClick[0],
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    ...
    error: function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {

        // Trigger an error on submit
        view.onSubmitComplete({
            file: file,
            xhr: xhr
        });

        // Allow file to be reuploaded !
        file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED;
        // this.cancelUpload(file);
        // this.disable();
        // this.uploadFile(file);

    }
});
```

Comment: Four years and half later it works for me with dropzone 5.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting it to `Dropzone.QUEUED` no longer works. If you look at the source code:

```
  enqueueFile(file) {
    if ((file.status === Dropzone.ADDED) && (file.accepted === true)) {
      file.status = Dropzone.QUEUED;
      if (this.options.autoProcessQueue) {
        return setTimeout((() => this.processQueue()), 0); // Deferring the call
      }
```

So here is what I did to make it work(reupload):

```
  file.status = Dropzone.ADDED
  dropzone.enqueueFile(file)
```

Assuming the `file.accepted` is `true` and `autoProcessQueue` is set to `true`

Comment: `Dropzone.QUEUED` is working in version 5.7.0